# Как работать с ресурсами из проекта?

Tags: java, файлы

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
```

Сюда нужно поместить txt файл, который должен лежать в jar файле(уже скомпилированной программе). Какие методы нужны, и в по какому пути положить текстовик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

положить его в папку `src/main/resources`

доставать так

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(Class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("адрес файла"));
```

путь к файлу указывать относительно папки `resources`.